# How can I put .aux files in separate folder using a command inside TexWorks?

Tags: auxiliary-files, texworks, output

I am using TexWorks and I need to put all help files produced by Latex into a subfolder relative to the folder where I have my master .tex file. On these StackExchange pages there are [answers to this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2977/bundle-tex-output-in-a-directory), but only for people using a command line  for latexing their .tex files. But I am using TexWorks, and do nok know how I can add such commands there.

My question is, can I put some command code into the "Arguments" window for pdflatex ? The two pictures below shows the location of the "Arguments" window.

To get the processing tools window in Texworks (picture 1): Edit/Preferences.../Typesetting tab

[image]

To get the "Tool Configuration" window in Texworks: in the Processing tools window, press "pdflatex"

[image]

Comment: Yes you can (move it so that it is before the $fullname).

Comment: You can use the same commands in Texworks as on the command line. On the lower screenshot, press the plus button and enter the `-aux_directory=yourdir` command. This command line option is only available for MiKTeX on Windows, apparently

Comment: @matth
Thanks for the answer, but when adding "-aux_directory=\mydir" or "-aux_directory=mydir" above the $fullname line, I get the errormessages:
miktex-pdftex.exe: Invalid command-line option          miktex-pdftex.exe: Data: unknown option

Comment: sorry, that was misspelled. I can't edit the comment anymore, but I added an answer below, including a screenshot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the below screenshot you can see how I configured Texworks to put aux files into the directory "test". The command to add is `-aux-directory=.\test` or any other directory. You have to create the directory manually, I think.

[image]

Comment: Your're welcome. Strangely, it seems as if \ works as well as / in the path.

Comment: Just a note that this only works with `MikTeX `and not `TeXLive`.

Comment: @PeterGrill I use TeXLive, Is there any alternative option for above solution?

Comment: @PHPst: Not that I know of.

Comment: Is there a command to do the same thing but with the .synctex file? That one is not moved to the aux-directory it seems.