# How can Bibtex find the auxiliary files it needs when these are stored in a subdirectory

Tags: bibtex, auxiliary-files

In order to make my major folder containing my master .tex file more clean, I have set Texworks to store all auiliary files in a subfolder called `auxfiles`. This was done by adding the following command line `-aux-directory=./auxfiles` into the Arguments list for the pdfLaTex processing tool in TexWorks (detailed explanation given in: [How can I put .aux files in separate folder using a command inside TexWorks?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44861/how-can-i-put-aux-files-in-separate-folder-using-a-command-inside-texworks)). However, after having done this BibTEx is no longer able to find the auxiliary files it needs. How do I make BibTex find the auxiliary files it needs, and in addition put its output into the `auxfiles` directory?

Comment: Did you try with `./auxfiles/$basename` as the argument for the BibTeX engine? What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify the action of the BibTeX engine in the preferences of TeXworks, so that the argument line is

```
./auxfiles/$basename
```

instead of simply `$basename`.

However, I suggest you to duplicate the engines: one normal BibTeX and another one, say BibTeX-AUX, that is modified in this way. Thus you'll be able to use both approaches.

Comment: But there's an issue. _main.aux_, the resulting .aux from compiling the main project, placed in **./auxfiles/**, has relative references inside it to other parts of the project, like **\@input{./part1.aux}**. This confuses bibtex as the correct location should be **\@input{./auxfiles/part1.aux}**. So, the compiler is not creating a correct _main.aux_ for bibtex to use! How to solve this?

Comment: @A.Vieira My personal opinion is that using subdirectories and `\include` should be avoided altogether

Comment: @egrep I agree now, but without it the compilation directory is a mess... Latex is so unclean with everything unfortunately.

Comment: In response to A. Viera's follow up question on how to manage included files from a master document: tell bibtex to include the corresponding base-directory (in your case `auxfiles`) with the addition of: -include-directory=auxfiles
So the complete command will be something like: bibtex.exe auxfiles/% -include-directory=auxfiles