# TexStudio + Bibtex + build/auxiliary folder

Tags: bibtex, texstudio, auxiliary-files

### Specs

Win7 64b - TexStudio 2.9.4 - Miktex

### Problem

Bibtex does not find *.aux file when I export my auxiliary files into a different directory, e.g. /auxiliary.

With current folder structure:

`root/
|_ main.tex
|_ bibliography.bib
|_ auxiliary/
   |_ *aux
   |_ ...`

PS. This solution is related to [Texstudio + Biber + build folder](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184204/texstudio-biber-build-folder) but different enough to provide exact settings here. Also, closely related to [How can Bibtex find the auxiliary files it needs when these are stored in a subdirectory](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46016/how-can-bibtex-find-the-auxiliary-files-it-needs-when-these-are-stored-in-a-subd)?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming the folder structure in the question, you should have the following configs.

Under `Options > Configure TexStudio ...> Commands`

- PdfLatex: `pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex` **`-aux-directory=./auxiliary/`**
- BibTex: `bibtex.exe` **`./auxiliary/%`**

Under `Options > Configure TexStudio ...> Build` (after you checked `Show Advanced Options` on the bottom-left corner):

- Add `./auxiliary/` into the `Log File` text-box in the lower pane with the `Build Options`.

**Note:** this does not work if you use external applications such as gnuplot. The external application won't be able to find the required build files now present outside of the root directory.

Comment: As of TexStudio 2.11 `Options > Configure TexStudio ...> Build` doesn't have any `Log File` option.

Comment: @Desik You need to tick the advanced options.

Answer (score 3):

Just if anyone needs the same under Linux, the option for PdfLatex has different name in TeXLive. Under `Options > Configure TexStudio ...> Commands` for PdfLatex one should put:

`pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-directory=auxiliary %.tex`

Also if you want to see your PDF in the built-in viewer window, under `Options > Configure TexStudio ...> Build` put `auxiliary` for PDF File too.

Comment: The method you mentioned works fine under Windows texstudio+texlive.