# Where is it defined in which folder TeXworks searches (and deletes) the utility files?

Tags: texworks

Where is it defined in which folder TeXworks searches (and deletes) the utility files like ".aux" etc?

Comment: What do you mean "utility files"? Are you asking about "TeXWorks configuration files" or about files like ".aux" etc? Please add some more words in your question.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44861/how-can-i-put-aux-files-in-separate-folder-using-a-command-inside-texworks the addition of `-aux-directory=.\mydir` will force this temporary files to go there... But If you are looking for the default of this output, I think that it depends on the specific command (pdflatex or latexmk or whatever) that TeXworks is using