# Bundle PDF+LaTeX source and open with Preview

Tags: pdftex, pdf, mac

There must be a solution to the following OS X and LaTeX related problem and I think it could be interesting to a lot of people: I would like to create a new file type ".pdflatex", a document bundle, which contains a LaTeX source file and its compiled PDF such that when I double click on this file the PDF is opened in Preview (or my favorite PDF viewer). Moreover, I would like that programs like DevonThink understand this and correctly preview/show the PDF file.

I want this to comfortably deal with PDF files and their LaTeX source. This should be possible in OS X but I really don't know how to do this.

(A similar but less specific question was already asked in [‘Bundle’ TeX output in a directory](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2977/bundle-tex-output-in-a-directory)  but there is no satisfactory answer).

Comment: There is a package that was released on ctan last month ([embedall](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/embedall)) that could provide an acceptable solution to your problem. I haven't tried it myself but was very interested to see it.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about that! But it's still not exactly what I was looking for as I still want to work with the LaTeX file. embedall seems to be right for archiving a finished project.

Comment: You could just create the PDF and put the source file(s) in it as an attachment. The `attachfile` package can aid in doing this. Since the file is actually a PDF file, double clicking it will display the document. And you can put a sort of link in the document that allows you to open (or save) the attachment.

Comment: See my comment above.

Comment: Duplicate of [Bundle PDF+LaTeX source in OS X and open with Preview](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19940691)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a duplicate of a question at another site: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19940691/821436